# Convert HarddiskVolume path to normal path

Tags: c++, windows, path

I have a device path like this

> Device\HarddiskVolume2\Windows\

and I want convert this to a normal path like this

> C:\Windows

I've try to use (_fullpath-_splitpath-etc...) but no new result. Which function does this job?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option is to replace `Device\` with `\\?\` like this:

```
\\?\HarddiskVolume2\Windows\
```

You can then open a handle to the directory using `CreateFile()` with the `FILE_FLAG_BACKUP` flag, and then call [`GetFinalPathNameByHandle()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364962%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to find the DOS path.

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char ** argv)
{
    wchar_t lpszFilePath[MAX_PATH + 1];
    DWORD dw;

    HANDLE hFile = CreateFileW(L"\\\\?\\HarddiskVolume2\\Windows\\", GENERIC_READ, 
        FILE_SHARE_READ | FILE_SHARE_WRITE | FILE_SHARE_DELETE, NULL, OPEN_EXISTING, 
        FILE_FLAG_BACKUP_SEMANTICS, NULL); 
    if (hFile == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE) 
    {
        printf("CreateFile: %u\n", GetLastError());
        return 1;
    }

    dw = GetFinalPathNameByHandleW(hFile, 
        lpszFilePath, _countof(lpszFilePath) - 1, VOLUME_NAME_DOS); 

    if (dw == 0)
    {
        printf("GetFPNBYH: %u\n", GetLastError());
        return 1;
    }
    else if (dw >= _countof(lpszFilePath))
    {
        printf("GetFPNBYH: output requires %u characters\n", dw);
        return 1;
    }

    printf("%ws\n", lpszFilePath);
    return 0;
}
```

Presumably there is an internal function that performs the conversion, and it might be possible to use it rather than having to open a handle, but as far as I know it isn't documented.

Comment: I try this, but not work `HANDLE hFile = CreateFile("\\?\HarddiskVolume2\Windows\\", GENERIC_WRITE, FILE_SHARE_WRITE, NULL, OPEN_EXISTING, FILE_FLAG_BACKUP_SEMANTICS, NULL);

 if (hFile == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
 {
  cout << "Invaild handle" << endl;
 }
 else
 {
  TCHAR lpszFilePath[MAX_PATH];
  GetFinalPathNameByHandle(hFile, lpszFilePath, sizeof(lpszFilePath), VOLUME_NAME_DOS);

  cout << lpszFilePath << endl;
 }`

Comment: @user3523388: I've corrected your code and added it to my answer.