# Replace wchar_t error return memory address

Tags: c++, winapi

I want to replace a specific character wchar_t. as a result it return memory address. is there a way to return replaced wchar_t?

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <Windows.h>
#include <Psapi.h>

using namespace std;


int main()
{
    wchar_t processPath[MAX_PATH];

    HANDLE hProcess = OpenProcess(PROCESS_QUERY_INFORMATION, FALSE, 3820);

    GetProcessImageFileName(hProcess, processPath, MAX_PATH);

    CloseHandle(hProcess);

    wchar_t * pwc;

    pwc = wcsstr(processPath, L"\\Device\\HardiskVolume1");

    wcscpy_s(pwc, 100, L"C:", 100);

    wcout << processPath;

    return 0;
}
```

Thank you

Comment: Use [`QueryFullProcessImageName()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684919(v=vs.85).aspx) instead which already gives you the Win32 path format. So there will be no need to do such a replacement.

Comment: @zett42 QueryFullProcessImageName is avaiable since vista. its mean in XP. it will not work. thats why i choose GetProcessImageName. and the problem is not the api. but the wcscpy_s argument. i don't know what i 
 i need to put into argument 2 and 4.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest that you use std::wstring, and then .replace, there isn't really a good 'replace' function when using c-strings:

```
LPCWSTR pwszReplace = L"string-of-interest";
std::size_t len = wcslen(pwszReplace);
std::wstring path(processPath),

std::size_t ndx = path.find(pwszReplace);
if(std::wstring::npos!=ndx)
{
path.replace(ndx, len, L"new-string");
}
std::wcout << L"path is now: " << path << std::endl;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `GetModuleFileNameEx` Windows XP and higher. Or `QueryFullProcessImageName` for Vista and higher.

Otherwise, you can't assume `"\\Device\\HardiskVolume1"` is always `"C:"`

See also this SO Q&A: [Convert HarddiskVolume path to normal path](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31017010/4603670)

Start by changing `"\Device"` to `"\\?"`:

```
`"\\Device\\HardiskVolume1\\path.exe"` //to 
`"\\\\?\\HardiskVolume1\\path.exe"` 

wchar_t buf[MAX_PATH];
wchar_t *ptr = wcsstr(processPath, L"\\Device");
if(ptr)
{
    wcscpy_s(buf, L"\\\\?");
    wcscat_s(buf, ptr + wcslen(L"\\Device"));
}
```

Now you can open `buf` in `CreateFile`, then use `GetFinalPathNameByHandle` to get

```
`"\\\\?\\C:\\path.exe"`
```

Note that `wcsstr` returns `NULL` if search string is not found. If search string was found and copy was successful, you end up overwriting `processPath` the way you have done that. Moreover, `wcscpy_s` is the secure version of `wcscpy`. If you don't want to use `wcscpy_s` correctly then just use `wcscpy` without using a random number like `100` as the argument.

Comment: the reason i don't want use getmodulefilenameex as i read there's problem with different bit running.  and i want to use wcsncpy_s cause that recomended from visual studio. and how to use wcsncpy_s ?

Comment: I don't know why you need `wcsncpy_s`. See edit on how to change the string. See also other answer. `std::wstring` is the C++ way to handle string manipulation, it takes care of security issues and is less susceptible to error.